# Quarkus MDC not propagated to Mutiny thread logs

Tags: quarkus, mdc, mutiny

I need to get a single MDC value to appear also in logs from mutiny.
It seems like MDC from caller thread is not automatically propagated to thread created by mutiny.
Actually thought that this would be done by quarkus-smallrye-context-propagation in the background.

Using Quarkus 2.10.3.Final

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-context-propagation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

java class

```
import org.jboss.logging.Logger;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sqs.SqsAsyncClient;


class MyClass{

@Inject
protected Logger log;
    
@Inject
protected SqsAsyncClient awsSqsClient;
 
 
 public Cancellable callAsync() {
        
        MDC.put("mykey", "myvalue");
        log.info("hello"); 
        // prints: 2022-10-04 16:04:28,651 INFO  [com....MyClass] (<thread name>) (myvalue) hello

        CompletableFuture<SendMessageResponse> cf = awsSqsClient.sendMessage(m ->
                m.queueUrl(<url>)
                        .messageGroupId(<mgid>)
                        .messageBody(<mb>));
                        
        return Uni.createFrom()
                .completionStage(cf)
                
                // prints: 2022-10-04 16:04:28,651 INFO  [com....MyClass] (<aws-java-sdk-NettyEventLoop-0-13>) () hello from mutiny
                .onItem().invoke(response -> log.info("hello from mutiny")) 
                
                .subscribe().with(ignored -> {});
}
```

Logs after call of `callAsync`

```
2022-10-04 16:04:28 INFO  [com....MyClass] (<thread name>) (myvalue) hello
2022-10-04 16:04:28 INFO  [com....MyClass] (<aws-java-sdk-NettyEventLoop-0-13>) () hello from mutiny
```

Comment: This has been fixed in Quarkus 2.12 or 2.13. Can you update?

Comment: Yes you are right, updated to 2.13 and it works as expected. Only one small issue, when adding log() resulting in `Uni.createFrom().completionStage(cf).log()` prints out its own log format, e.g.  `[--> Uni.UniCreateFromKnownItem.0 | onSubscribe()`. Is there a way that this custom logger is also logging as defined by `quarkus.log.console.format` ?

Comment: You can configure the logger name, or even how it's logged :(https://javadoc.io/doc/io.smallrye.reactive/mutiny/latest/io.smallrye.mutiny/io/smallrye/mutiny/infrastructure/Infrastructure.html).

Comment: @Clement I came across Infrastructure.OperatorLogger , but I have no idea how/where to set logger format with that

Comment: Easiest way I found to redefine logging format of Uni/Muti logs was to copy io.smallrye.mutiny.infrastructure.Infrastructure.PrintOperatorEventOperatorLogger to a new class e.g. CustomLogger and setting it by `Infrastructure.setOperatorLogger(new CustomLogger());`. At first I just replaced  `System.out.println(message);` by ` Log.info(message)` wondering why this is not default behaviour.